# What is this certificate?

Tags: windows-10, certificate

I am running Windows 10. When I open `certlm`, I see the following:

[image: certlm image]

- What is this '[not avaliable]' certificate?
- Is it just the Disallowed List of certificates and if so, why is it a certificate in itself and not a folder?
- Is it a concern in terms of PC security?

Comment: It’s not a certificate at all, that much is obvious. ;)

Comment: @DanielB How is it obvious? The icon? I do notice that at the bottom of the window it says, "Untrusted Certificates store contains no certificates". What is it if not a certificate?

Comment: It’s a [“Certificate Trust List”](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for the link. So does it store the hashes of untrusted certificates?

Comment: @CharlieRB Is this issue definitely specific to Windows 10?

Comment: By adding the tag I am not making any claims or assumtions. I added the tag because you make the connection in the first sentence of the post. Why would you say that if you didn't think it relevant. Therefore, the tag was added.

Comment: @CharlieRB OK, thanks. I was just wondering because of the tag description. The issue is, of course, related to Windows 10.